# onActivityResult() not called after startIntentSenderForResult()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-billing

**UPDATE:** I have now tried to run the same flow from a regular `Activity`, and getting the same result - `onActivityResult()` not fired. 
Tested on two differenet physical devices (running android 4.4 and 5.1)

**Note:** This question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084565/onactivityresult-not-called-after-startintentsenderforresult) before, yet this case is different, thus the accepted answer doesn't solve it.

From `MainActivity` we start a `FragmentDialog`:

```
public void ShowDialog(View v)
{
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
    myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"");
}
```

Then, from `MyDialog` we call

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = bundle.getParcelable(BUY_INTENT);
        if( null == pendingIntent)  return false;

getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult
                (pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
```

The above indeed invokes the Google Billing Fragment, however, **niether `MyDialog.onActivityResult()` nor `MainActivity.onActivityResult()`** get called.

Comment: Is your activity in `singleInstance`?

Comment: @Miao1007 no sir, a normal activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YGTBFKM!

After a **long** kong-fu session, I've finally found that ***as opposed to the mentioned at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)***  the `requestCode` used for `startIntentSenderForResult()` **CANNOT BE ARBITRARY**! I don't have a specific cutoff number, but values below 1000 seems to work fine.